# Display RSS feed item on intranet via php

Tags: php, rss

I've been at this the whole day.  We have an intranet at the office, some PC's does not have internet access.  I'm trying to get this website's RSS (**http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/**)into a table with images and display it on the intranet, is this at all possible?  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/on_this_day/front_page/rss.xml
```

There's your XML, just use SimpleXML to get your data from it. Very simple really.

Something to get you started:

```
$a = curl_init("http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/on_this_day/front_page/rss.xml");
curl_setopt($a, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$b = curl_exec($a);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($b);

var_dump($xml);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, will start investigating, will post back if I have a result and accept your answer